# WPF Telerik add reference to theme library breaks Prism Regions

Tags: c#, reference, telerik, prism

This is a weird one.

When I add reference on my WPF project to any telerik Telerik.Windows.Themes libraries, it breaks my Prism Region manager and my UI doesn't load.

There is no code change whatsoever, installing / removing the reference causes/fix the issue.

How that can be ? Adding the reference will just copy the binary..?

Comment: Reference like "nuget" or "file reference"? Installing a nuget package can do all kind of things.

Comment: In that instance it was nugget

Comment: @Damien Is it only if you add the single themes NuGet package or does it happen, if you switch from using WPF only to Telerik controls (e.g. adding all necessary NuGet packages including themes and / or replacing controls with Telerik controls)?

Comment: Not sure to grasp your question @thatguy. It only happens when I add a reference to any telerik "Theme" package. I've never had any issue with other nugget package. Note that the particular package is noxaml. If I copy the dll file manually and reference them as the theming explains, then it works fine. Lost like 5h trying to understand what was broken in my code, in fact it was the reference which is the last thing that came in mind.